# An error occurs when flink writes data to hive insert overwrite

Tags: hive, apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-batch

I needed to set up an offline repository, so I used flink and hive. Error was reported when I used partition overwrite insert into hive.

```
com.py.project.tproc.data.common.exception.BigDataRuntimeException: Streaming mode not support overwrite.
```

The above exception indicates that insert overwrite cannot be used in a streaming environment, so I set batch mode, but this error is still reported

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env   = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(address, port);
        env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);
        
        env.setParallelism(parallelism);
        StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().build());
```

I want to be able to write data to hive using insert overwrite normally, and I must use a remote environment because my business scenario requires it. What should I do?

Forget the good answer